# Hidden Index on a table

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

I am running into an issues with locating index

In SSMS, if I expand Users>Indexes, I do not see an index named "_dta_index_Users_5_1466188719_88410000_K1_K6_K2_7_10_11"

But I can see a statistics created for it.

Also when I search for indexes on "Users" by running this query

SELECT index_id, name FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Users')

It appears in the result "_dta_index_Users_5_1466188719_88410000_K1_K6_K2_7_10_11"

So the question is why I cannot see this index in SSMS? The index is not disabled and not user created since all our indexes start with IX_USERS_XXX

Any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it hypothetical? (What is the value of `is_hypothetical` in `sys.indexes`?)

Comment: No, it is on our production server. I was looking through our statistics and found it but cannot associate it with any indexes on the table

Comment: The value of the index is 42 for index_Id

Comment: And for the `is_hypothetical` column?

Comment: not sure about the value of column... are you asking what columns are included in this index? or is there a query to run to find out

Comment: What does `SELECT index_id, name, is_hypothetical FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Users')` return?

Comment: I didn't knew about is_hypothetical till now... thanks!

Comment: No probs. It's created by the database tuning advisor. Can someone be running a session at the moment or has it been left behind without being cleaned up?

Comment: Any suggestions how to clean it up or a link?

Comment: See the script in the dupe or https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/hypothetical-indexes-index-tuning-wizard/